# BizTalk Send Port : (413) Request Entity Too Large. The page was not displayed because the request entity is too large

Tags: c#, wcf, biztalk, wcf-binding

We have a WCF Service hosted on IIS 10, We have a send Port WCF-Custom(BasicHttpBinding) through which I am sending an excel file by converting to Base64 format in a pipeline.

If I send the same message to a folder using File adapter there is no issue but while using WCF-Custom(BasicHttpBinding) I am getting below error
"System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large.
The page was not displayed because the request entity is too large."

Note: My file size is 37MB, so tried setting up max for all the attributes, I have checked Binding name also.

Can Anyone have any Solutions, how can I resolve this issue?

Here's my Send port Binding configuration below
[image]
[image]

Below is WCF Binding Conffiguration
[image]

Comment: Have you also checked the settings in IIS

Comment: @Dijkgraaf, Can you pls elaborate on what settings should I check in IIS ?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf, Also can you psl tell me what file will changed if I change configuration in IIS I am asking this because its working env and has many services hosted there

Comment: You can try removing the binding name and make sure both client and server web.config are configured.

Comment: Hi @Lan Huang, I have tried removing Binding name and made sure the configuration is there on both the sides but no luck. Pls note in Biztalk its just WCF-Custom Port configuration is there

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue before you also need to increase your `receiveTimeout` settings. Try the maximum timeout settings for this property.

[image]